# Regular transfer of .csv to database

Tags: mysql, csv

I am working on a program that will regularly read the data from a .csv file and import it to my database. The csv is a copy from a database on another server so the table structure will be different when I upload to the new one.

What I am unsure of is the best method to do this on a nightly basis, and hopefully automate the process. Any suggestions?
The database is MySQL on an apache server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) query on a timed script with PHP, Python, or other language to upload into temp table:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv' 
INTO TABLE tempname
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Then run an append query migrating the different structured temp table data into final table.

```
INSERT INTO finaltable (Col1, Col2, Col3,...)
SELECT [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], ... FROM tempname
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution in my opinion is create a PHP script to manipulate csv data and match the format of the file to the tables in your database. After which, you can set up a cron job(linux) or scheduled task(windows) to run the script automatically at your desired time and recursion. Hope this helps you.